# When to use the Jumbotron?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is just a basic question, in what events do you use a `jumbotron`? Do you always need to include a `jumbotron` when writing in the Bootstrap Framework? Examples of when to use the `jumbotron` is appreciated.

Comment: Here's their own example, http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron/

Comment: when you want heading for your page that time you can use jumbtron.

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, jumbotron is just a component, like a big banner usually on the top of your home page. Think of it like a big hoarding a visitor would see when they visit your site. When you are using bootstrap, I think the components that you might need 99% of the times is the [grid](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid). Rest depends on your website's requirements.

The grid is useful for making a row/column style layout of your webpage that's responsive (flows depending on the size of the device).

In the page below, you can get rid of the grey box (Jumbotron heading container) if you don't need it.
[image]

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your detailed comment, Ken!

Comment: Be sure to check out this link with different layouts: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#examples

Answer (score 2):

`Jumbotron` is simply a styled element. Bootstrap has some default properties applied to that element, making it a very good 'eye catcher'.

You don't need to include it, but you can if you like it. I'd use it to display the main business concepts, to display commercial items or discounts.

A nice example of use-cases is to look at commercial websites. [here](https://www.zalando.nl/heren-home/) you can see how they used a slideshow for promotion, inside a `jumbotron`-like element for the eye catcher.

Using it is simply a matter of personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

Jumbotron is one of Bootstrap helpers utility when developing sites. It is not necessary to have it in your project, it all depends how your design is structured. Basically with this component you can optionally increase the size of headings and add a lot of margin for landing page content. Another definition from w3 would say that jumbotron indicates a big box for calling extra attention to some special content or information. With this said it is place where you want to point out something, maybe some title, company quote of some nice graphics.