# Bootstrap Jumbotron vs Container-fluid

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Why do we have a Jumbotron if we have the Container-fluid?

I have seen a lot of explanations saying that is because it is full width, but the container fluid is not.

Help me out with that please thanks =)

Comment: The primary difference is in the padding applied to jumbotron. It has quite a bit at anywhere from 30px to 48px to 60px depending whereas container-fluid has no padding applied. In general, pages that are designed with a bit of padding away from the edge of the screen look better. Not a lot of web pages you'll visit on the web contain their main content from edge to edge of the entire screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the difference between .container and  .container-fluid [here](http://rateyo.fundoocode.ninja/)
and as for Jumbotron. Think of it as a hero section which sets below navbar. You can read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37857252/when-to-use-the-jumbotron)

Hope I helped

Comment: @AlexisSantos Check all images [here](https://www.google.co.kr/search?q=jumbotron+website+examples&newwindow=1&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjfra_kwJTUAhVBxLwKHURNA6UQ_AUICigB&biw=1366&bih=672#newwindow=1&tbm=isch&q=jumbotron++examples). As you see in all web pages they have nice image and text after navigation bar. they are all jumbotrons. You use jumbotron to show images and an important text to the user. it doesn't affect the size of the page. Container and container-fluid have impact on the page width. It is  one of the classes of Bootstrap for HTML selectors